# How to handle input validation errors using Page Object Model?

Tags: java, generics, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Page Object Model.

I have a form in which there are input fields if those fields remain empty and submit is clicked, it gives an error.
I want to create a method such that if errors are displayed it should remain on the same page, otherwise it should go to next page.

I am implementing like this:

```
public CreatePage extends AbstractPage{
    public <T extends AbstractPage> T clickContinue(){
            if(error.isDisplayed())
                return this;
            else
                return ConfirmPage.class); 
        }
    }

    public ConfirmPage extends AbstractPage{
    }
```

Error - `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ConfirmPage to T`

`ConfirmPage` and `CreatePage` are in different files.

Comment: Are ConfirmPage and ConfirmOrderPage two separate classes or should that error just be for ConfirmPage?

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `public CreatePage<T> extends AbstractPage <T>`?